Python Azure Search contains filter isn't working
I'm trying to filter documents in my azure search index using the filter expression. I specifically want to filter the file names using a 'contains' filter and this is the search parameter I'm providing via langchain.
search_kwargs={'k': 8, 'search_type': 'semantic_hybrid', 'filters': f"search.ismatch('Summary', 'file_name', 'full', 'any')"}
vector_search_retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(search_kwargs = search_kwargs)


But this filter doesn't seem to be working at all. The retriever returns all the files instead of the just the ones filtered by file name. What is wrong about this syntax?

HI @AnonymousMe, search.ismatch function is used for text search within documents, not for filtering specific fields based on content. If you want to filter documents by file name containing a specific substring use the contains function in the OData filter syntax

This is the error I get when using contains function "() Invalid expression: Unsupported function call: contains. Note that you can achieve similar functionality by using the search.ismatch() function. See the documentation for Azure Search filters for more details: https://aka.ms/azsearchodataexpr Parameter name: $filter Code: Message: Invalid expression: Unsupported function call: contains.. See the documentation for Azure Search filters for more details: "

search_kwargs={'k': 8, 'search_type': 'semantic_hybrid', 'filters': f"search.ismatch('Summary', 'file_name', 'full', 'any')"}

filter is wrong.
First, it is "filter", not "filters".
It can't be f-string. f-string is for python. And retriever can not evaluate .ismatch. You have to specify it as dictionary format.
# Use a filter to only retrieve documents from a specific paper
docsearch.as_retriever(
    search_kwargs={'filter': {'paper_title':'GPT-4 Technical Report'}}
)

Remember, your filter keys should match with the metadata definition.
